# How to deal with "[asf XX] too long payload" message in ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to cut a small section of a video using the following sentence:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i video.wmv -ss 00:20:02 -to 00:20:09 -crf 22  "C:\test.mp4" -y
```

However, ffmpeg hangs showing messages like:

```
[asf @ 03327b00] too long payload 0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x
       Last message repeated 352 times 
[asf @ 03327b00] too long payload 0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x
      Last message repeated 331 times
```

I have waited for more than 30 minutes and ffmpeg did not finish the cutting. Does anyone have any idea how to solve this?

Any suggestion will be appreciated

PD. the ffprobe output of the source file is the following:

```
ffprobe version N-81831-g97e7f03 Copyright (c) 2007-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-nvenc --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-libebur128 --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      55. 32.100 / 55. 32.100
  libavcodec     57. 60.101 / 57. 60.101
  libavformat    57. 51.102 / 57. 51.102
  libavdevice    57.  0.102 / 57.  0.102
  libavfilter     6. 63.100 /  6. 63.100
  libswscale      4.  1.100 /  4.  1.100
  libswresample   2.  2.100 /  2.  2.100
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
[asf @ 03b7afe0] too long payload
    Last message repeated 159 times
Input #0, asf, from 'F:\video.wmv':
  Metadata:
    WMFSDKVersion   : 11.0.5721.5145
    WMFSDKNeeded    : 0.0.0.0000
    IsVBR           : 0
    DeviceConformanceTemplate: M
  Duration: 01:41:25.95, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1649 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: wmv2 (WMV2 / 0x32564D57), yuv420p, 640x480, 1500 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: wmav2 (a[1][0][0] / 0x0161), 44100 Hz, 2 channels, fltp, 128 kb/s
```

Comment: [Download a recent version](https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/) (the daily generated one, not 4.1.1) and try again.

Comment: @llogan exactly the same result. No difference

Comment: [Report it as a bug](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/). Make sure to provide your command (from the new ffmpeg), the complete console output (you can trim most of the repeating lines if they show up hundreds of times), and a short sample file that has the same issue if you can.